# Cargar video en un videoView android desde un link que está en un textview

Tags: android, video

Estoy tratando de cargar un video en un videoView desde un link que tengo en un `TextView`, pero me manda que no se puede reproducir y he probado con extensiones mp4 y de youtube directamente y nada. ¿Alguna idea?

```
 Intent i = getIntent();
    String video = i.getStringExtra("video");
    tv2.setText(video);

    String uriPath = "video";
    Uri uri = Uri.parse(uriPath);

    // Se crean los controles multimedia.
    MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(this);

    // Inicializa la VideoView.
    videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView);
    // Asigna los controles multimedia a la VideoView.
    videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);
```

Alli traigo el url y otros datos de otro Activity, la variable video contiene el url del video.

Answer (score 1):

Es importante que el video que trates de reproducir sea generado con los codecs soportados por Android:

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/media-formats.html

Como opción puedes usar el mismo reproductor del dispositivo, en el caso de que el VideoView no soporte el video, este es un ejemplo:

```
    String videourl = "http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4";
    Uri uri = Uri.parse(videourl);
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
    intent.setDataAndType(uri, "video/mp4");
    startActivity(intent);
```

---

**Abrir video youtube en player:**

```
      String youtubeVideoId = "t6LbzHMDVUg"; //Id video.
            Intent appIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("vnd.youtube:" + youtubeVideoId));         
            try {
                startActivity(appIntent);  //Abre con aplicación.
            } catch (ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
            //En caso de no existir la aplicación instalada se abre mediante el navegador.
            Intent webIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                    Uri.parse("http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=" + youtubeVideoId));
                startActivity(webIntent);
            }
```

Comment: Oh, entiendo muchas gracias, lo probé y en efecto con una extensión mp4 si me funciona perfectamente, mmm pero para reproducir un video de un enlace de YouTube si el enlace lo tengo en un text view almacenado en una variable y deseo que cargue el video de ese enlace de YouTube se puede?

Comment: Claro, pero lo realizaría en la aplicación youtube instalada en el dispositivo.

Comment: vale vale, muchísimas gracias por tu ayuda

Comment: @XavierEspinosa agregué un ejemplo de como abrir videos youtube, si deseas tener el player dentro del WebView, puede ser que en ocasiones no se reproduzca porque es un navegador limitado.

Comment: vale, gracias, ya ps lo solucioné. En efecto los url de los videos deben llevar la extensión mp4 para poder que se reproduzcan :/